How to use the Stata equivalent of a foreach loop in R with mutate()
I have 4 different variables in my raw data (all starting with the prefix raw_), followed by combinations of hours/money and school/social. In my real data, I have many more options for each value of variable, so it ends up being quite a long chunk of code to have to iterate through 4 times.
There must be a simple way to do the equivalent of a foreach loop in Stata (which I use more frequently for data cleaning) in R to condense the 4 iterations to just 1.

In Stata, the loop would look something like:
foreach suffix in hours_school hours_social money_school money_social {
   gen olderch_`suffix' = .
   replace olderch_`suffix' = 90 if raw_`suffix' == "90% or more 10% or less"
   replace olderch_`suffix' = 10 if raw_`suffix' == "10% or less 90% or more"
}


And here's my current version of R code that I'd love to condense similarly:
d <- d %>% 
  mutate(olderch_hours_school = case_when (
    raw_hours_school == "90% or more 10% or less" ~ 90,
    raw_hours_school == "10% or less 90% or more" ~ 10
  ))

d <- d %>% 
  mutate(olderch_hours_social = case_when (
    raw_hours_social == "90% or more 10% or less" ~ 90,
    raw_hours_social == "10% or less 90% or more" ~ 10
  ))

d <- d %>% 
  mutate(olderch_money_school = case_when (
    raw_money_school == "90% or more 10% or less" ~ 90,
    raw_money_school == "10% or less 90% or more" ~ 10
  ))

d <- d %>% 
  mutate(olderch_money_social = case_when (
    raw_money_social == "90% or more 10% or less" ~ 90,
    raw_money_social == "10% or less 90% or more" ~ 10
  ))



Are you asking how to do the same thing to multiple variables?

Essentially yes

Edit: As requested in a comment, answer examples create new columns based on the originals.
dplyr::across() (docs) allows you to apply a function across multiple columns in your data frame. You can adapt your case_when statements by adding ~ to make a lambda function and using . to represent each column.
You can provide a vector of all columns being transformed, or use a selection helper, such as everything() or starts_with().
Test data follows the examples.
library(dplyr)

glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 10
#> Columns: 4
#> $ raw_hours_school <chr> "90% or more 10% or less", "90% or more 10% or less",…
#> $ raw_hours_social <chr> "10% or less 90% or more", "10% or less 90% or more",…
#> $ raw_money_school <chr> "90% or more 10% or less", "10% or less 90% or more",…
#> $ raw_money_social <chr> "90% or more 10% or less", "10% or less 90% or more",…

df |>
  mutate(across(
    c(raw_hours_school, raw_hours_social,
      raw_money_school, raw_money_social),
    ~ case_when(. ==  "90% or more 10% or less" ~ 90,
                . == "10% or less 90% or more" ~ 10),
    .names = "new_{.col}")) %>%
  setNames(gsub('_raw', '', names(.)))
#>           raw_hours_school        raw_hours_social        raw_money_school
#> 1  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less
#> 2  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more
#> 3  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less
#> 4  10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less
#> 5  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less
#> 6  10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less
#> 7  10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more
#> 8  10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more
#> 9  90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less
#> 10 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more
#>           raw_money_social new_hours_school new_hours_social new_money_school
#> 1  90% or more 10% or less               90               10               90
#> 2  10% or less 90% or more               90               10               10
#> 3  90% or more 10% or less               90               10               90
#> 4  10% or less 90% or more               10               90               90
#> 5  10% or less 90% or more               90               10               90
#> 6  90% or more 10% or less               10               90               90
#> 7  90% or more 10% or less               10               10               10
#> 8  90% or more 10% or less               10               90               10
#> 9  90% or more 10% or less               90               90               90
#> 10 10% or less 90% or more               90               90               10
#>    new_money_social
#> 1                90
#> 2                10
#> 3                90
#> 4                10
#> 5                10
#> 6                90
#> 7                90
#> 8                90
#> 9                90
#> 10               10

df |>
  mutate(across(
   starts_with("raw"),
    ~ case_when(. ==  "90% or more 10% or less" ~ 90,
                . == "10% or less 90% or more" ~ 10),
   .names = "new_{.col}")) %>%
  setNames(gsub('_raw', '', names(.)))
#>           raw_hours_school        raw_hours_social        raw_money_school
#> 1  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less
#> 2  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more
#> 3  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less
#> 4  10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less
#> 5  90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less
#> 6  10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less
#> 7  10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more
#> 8  10% or less 90% or more 90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more
#> 9  90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less
#> 10 90% or more 10% or less 90% or more 10% or less 10% or less 90% or more
#>           raw_money_social new_hours_school new_hours_social new_money_school
#> 1  90% or more 10% or less               90               10               90
#> 2  10% or less 90% or more               90               10               10
#> 3  90% or more 10% or less               90               10               90
#> 4  10% or less 90% or more               10               90               90
#> 5  10% or less 90% or more               90               10               90
#> 6  90% or more 10% or less               10               90               90
#> 7  90% or more 10% or less               10               10               10
#> 8  90% or more 10% or less               10               90               10
#> 9  90% or more 10% or less               90               90               90
#> 10 10% or less 90% or more               90               90               10
#>    new_money_social
#> 1                90
#> 2                10
#> 3                90
#> 4                10
#> 5                10
#> 6                90
#> 7                90
#> 8                90
#> 9                90
#> 10               10

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  raw_hours_school = sample(c("90% or more 10% or less",
                          "10% or less 90% or more"),
                        10, replace = TRUE),
  raw_hours_social = sample(c("90% or more 10% or less",
                          "10% or less 90% or more"),
                        10, replace = TRUE),
  raw_money_school = sample(c("90% or more 10% or less",
                          "10% or less 90% or more"),
                        10, replace = TRUE),
  raw_money_social = sample(c("90% or more 10% or less",
                          "10% or less 90% or more"),
                        10, replace = TRUE)
)


Thanks, this is really helpful. This transforms the 4 raw columns though, right? Ideally I'd create 4 new columns (could call them 'new_hours_school', or something)

Hi @a_todd12, by providing something to the .names argument you can create new columns. I've updated my answer to show how to create new columns with names based on the originals.

Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. This seems like the rare instance that Stata is actually quite a bit simpler than R
